# Mathematica cannot simplify a rather simple expression with only one term

Tags: simplifying-expressions

I run this code on Mathematica 11.2,

```
Simplify[1/x^2,Assumptions->(1/x^2==1)]
```

and hope to get 1, but Mathematica returns me `1/x^2`.

That's really unexpected that Mathematica cannot simplify such a simple expression. Can someone find out the reason or it's just a bug?

Comment: This works: Simplify[1/x^2, Assumptions -> (x == 1)]

Comment: This also works `1/x^2 /. Solve[(1/x^2 == 1), x][[1]]`

Comment: @chris Thank you! Your code works well, but I still wonder why my code does not work... It looks like that the expression and assumption match exactly, but Mathematica did not recognize it...

Comment: My experience is that `Simplify` is limited in its use of equations as assumptions. Simple direct substitution, something that is obvious to humans, is not always tried. It is, or something equivalent to it is, in the case `x == a`. Interestingly, `Simplify[1/f[x^2], Assumptions->(1/x^2 == 1)]` works. Why? I don’t know. `1/x^2` is `Power[x, -2]` and `x^2` is `Power[x, 2]` — maybe it handles negative exponents in a cautious way. Or it may be limited in handling multiple solutions: @Chris’s variant works but not `x==1 || x==-1`, which is equivalent to the original assumption.

Comment: Another quirk: `Simplify[z == 1/x^2, Assumptions -> 1/x^2 == 1]` produces `z == 1`. Algebraic expressions and equations are treated differently, I guess.

Comment: like @Michael E2's: `Eliminate[Reduce[z==1/x^2 && 1/x^2==1], x]` produces `z==1`.

Comment: A nice simple way: (1/x^2) /. {1/x^2 -> 1}

Comment: @MichaelE2 Thank you for your kind comment! Now I know it's not a good idea to impose equations as assumptions in 'Simplify'. Looks like I had better use a replacement rule like bills's.

Comment: Another way to look at it is that `Simplify` tries to solve a discrete minimization problem, namely, starting from a given expression, to find the code with the fewest leaves under a specified set of transformations. That is not always the same as what people mean by "mathematically simplify." They are close because many of the transformations are mathematical identities. Sometimes it is better to use an algebraic solver, like `Reduce`, `Solve`, `Eliminate`, etc. For instance, `z /. Solve[z == 1/x^2 && 1/x^2 == 1, z, {x}]` gives what you want and will likely work in more complicated cases....

Comment: ...But one way is not always better than the other. Can't imagine a better to do `Simplify[Sqrt[x^2], x < 0]` than `Simplify`.  The problem with replacement rules is that the pattern on the left has to match what's in the expression. In algebraic expression, it often does not. For instance, `6/x^2 + 4/x^4 /. {2/x^2 -> 1}`, which one might like to simplify to `3+1` or `4`.